# Get the file names from multiple file upload field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write an ajax uploader using Jquery.
In the html I can write a multiple upload field like:

```
<input type='file' multiple='multiple' name='files[]'>
```

But, how can I get the values from this field?
When I used:

```
   $('input[type='file']').val();
```

or

```
   $('input[type='file']').attr('value');
```

I only got the file name for the first file I selected to upload. Is there a way I can get an array containing all files?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [HTML5 Files API](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/) means that the `input` will have a `files` property. You can access it like so:

```
var fileList = document.getElementById("yourInput").files;
```

That returns a [`FileList`](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/#filelist-section), which I believe is an array-like object containing all files selected by the user, so you would be able to iterate over it as normal:

```
for(var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
    //Do something with individual files
}
```

But it won't work in browsers that don't support HTML5, and I don't think it was supported in IE until version 9. If those older browsers are important to you, your best bet is probably to use a Flash or Java based uploader.