# How to get names of all files in the <input type="file"> input that has the multiple attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, file, file-upload, input

I have a input with the `multiple` attribute on my page:

```
<input type="file" accept="video/*" required multiple id="input-file-video">
```

If the user selects, let's say, 3 files at once, the input is going to display just : "3 files selected", but I want to get the names of all files that are selected. I also tried accessing the `value` property of the input:

```
document.getElementById("input-file-video").value;
```

But that returns just the name of the first file.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the file names from multiple file upload field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684011/get-the-file-names-from-multiple-file-upload-field)

Comment: MDN Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
var inp = document.getElementById('input-file-video');
for (var i = 0; i < inp.files.length; ++i) {
  var name = inp.files.item(i).name;
  alert("file name: " + name);
}
```

In jQuery, `$('#input-file-video').get(0).files;` will return the list of files that are uploaded. So you can loop through and get the files names.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about the files property.