# Bootstrap multiple file selection - show only first file

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap custom file input - and this is very good thing, but i dont know how show all my uploaded files. Every time when i try select multiple files and upload them - all passed correctly, except this - in input form shows only first file.

Code

```
<form>
  <div class="custom-file">
    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile">
    <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choose file</label>
  </div>
</form>

<script>
// Add the following code if you want the name of the file appear on select
$(".custom-file-input").on("change", function() {
  var fileName = $(this).val().split("\\").pop();
  $(this).siblings(".custom-file-label").addClass("selected").html(fileName);
});
</script>
```

I can add `multiple = ""` to form code - but what should I add to make all files for upload appear in the input line?

Comment: Usually, this depends on the browser you are using. You could use the [File API](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_file) and handle the displaying of the file names by yourself ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/File)).

Comment: Try to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32745331/how-to-get-names-of-all-files-in-the-input-type-file-input-that-has-the-mult

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want to see? I am not sure how the value attribute behaves on file-input but you can definitely see every file in the files property of the input so I just created a string out of it.

```js
// Add the following code if you want the name of the file appear on select
$(".custom-file-input").on("change", function() {
  var files = Array.from(this.files)
  var fileName = files.map(f =>{return f.name}).join(", ")
  $(this).siblings(".custom-file-label").addClass("selected").html(fileName);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form>
  <div class="custom-file">
    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile" multiple>
    <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choose file</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you can access FileObject via `.prop('files')` of input element, see this test below

```js
$("input").on("input", function() {
  var names = $(this).prop('files');
  for( var i = 0; i < names.length ; i++){
    console.log( names[ i ].name )
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form>
  <div class="custom-file">
    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile" multiple="multiple">
    <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choose file</label>
  </div>
</form>
```