# File uploading and validation

Tags: javascript, html, css, validation, jquery-file-upload

I am using JQuery Validation Plug-in - https://jqueryvalidation.org/ with Drag n Drop file uploader Plug-in https://css-tricks.com/drag-and-drop-file-uploading/.

Please help me to get the Validator to highlight if the user hasn't submitted a file.

The relevant HTML is here -

```
<div class="filearea1">
<div class="box" id="uploader1">
    <input hidden="true" type="file" id="upload-file" name="upload-files[]" class="box__file" />
    <div class="box__input2">
        <label class="box__input3" for="upload-file">
            <i class="fa fa-upload fa-2x"></i>
            <span id="upload-filename"></span>
            <span id="upload-filetip">
                <span class="box__dragndrop" style="color: gray"> Drag File here (one only) .</span>
            </span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `if the user hasn't uploaded a file` when? When user submits the a `form`?

Comment: Hi Mosh,  yes!  The file has to be attached.  Therefore it should be attached when clicking on "submit".  If it isnt attached the validation should say "please attach a file".

Comment: Read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/833012/863110)

Comment: Thanks Mosh.  That does help but I was hoping for a bespoke answer regarding the combined use of the Validator and Uploader.  There probably isn't such an answer so I will have to be creative!